# Is there a way to name the volume when runInstance is called?

Tags: php, sdk, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Using AWS SDK PHP2 with Composer.

I've got this so far:

```
$new = array('ImageId' => 'ami-xxx', 'MinCount' => 1, 'MaxCount' => 1, 'KeyName' => 'xxx', 'SecurityGroups' => array('xxx'), 'InstanceType' => 't1.micro', 'BlockDeviceMappings' => array(array('DeviceName' => '/dev/sda1', 'Ebs' => array('DeleteOnTermination' => true))));
```

I don't see anything in the docs for tags in runInstances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tags can only be added to existing instances - you can't specify them when launching new ones. You'll need to make a separate call after the runInstance call succeeds.

Comment: I think thats why I couldn't create a tag for it immediately after the runInstance call either (It returned an empty VolumeId). I saw functions that wait for the instance to be running which is probably when I want to call createTag.